# how I can change the background color and text color of a textbox done with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, background-color

how I can change the background color of a textbox done with Tkinter in python?
i used the code below but i can't understand why it doesn't work

```
from Tkinter import *

def onclick():
   pass

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()

text.tag_add("here", "1.0", "1.4")
text.tag_add("start", "1.8", "1.13")
text.tag_config("here", background="black", foreground="green")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6):

It does work. If you insert text:

```
text.insert(1.0, 'Hello World')
```

before calling the `tag_add` and `tag_config` methods, that tag will be attached to the inserted text. However, at the time it's currently being called, there's no index to insert the tag at, so there's effectively no tag.

If you want to modify the text contents real-time as the user types in the widget, you can bind the text widget to a keypress event, which calls a function that adds and configures tags for the text widget:

```
from Tkinter import *

def track_change_to_text(event):
    text.tag_add("here", "1.0", "1.4")
    text.tag_config("here", background="black", foreground="green")

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

text.bind('<KeyPress>', track_change_to_text)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i would change ALL the textbox color not only the background color of the text

Comment: Okay. And you want to use tags for that? Or you just don't know how to do that?

Comment: i don't know how do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bg` to determine the background color, when creating the text box itself:

```py
text = Text(root, bg = 'black')
```